# Auth0 Next.js error withPageAuthRequired You should not access 'res' after getServerSideProps resolves

Tags: next.js, auth0

I seem to be getting the error:

`You should not access 'res' after getServerSideProps resolves.`

With the following code:

```
export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuthRequired({
  async getServerSideProps(ctx){
    // access the user session
    const session = getSession(ctx.req,ctx.res);
    return {props:{
      customProp:'bar'
    }};
   }
});
```

This code comes directly from https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/modules/helpers_with_page_auth_required.html#withpageauthrequiredoptions

I didn't know if there was a way to get rid of this warning when implementing auth0 I'm on Next.js 12.0.4 & auth0 ^1.6.1

What would be the best way to get rid of this error?

Comment: FYI, the Auth0 Nextjs SDK has an issue on the github repo which is tracked here: https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/issues/524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, it's a warning

This warning is [decribed](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/13910) here, no simple [solution](https://github.com/featureboard/sdks/issues/2)

P.S. I have the same stuff in my projects, waiting for update fix. This bug appeared in next^12.0.2 version

Comment: Sorry on my miswording there meant to type warning, and alright just wanted to make sure I wasn't implementing it incorrectly or introducing a security vulnerability

Comment: Is this still the case, I have come across this issue also?